# When does any solution of an i.v.p. converges to some steady state?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes, initial-value-problems, steady-state

**Preliminaries**

Let $A = [0, 1]^N$.
Consider a dynamical system $\dot{x} = f(x)$, where $x = x(t) : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^N$ and $f : A \to \mathbb{R}^N$, where each $f_i$  is in the class $\mathcal{C}^2(A).$

Suppose that the following holds true:

> For any initial condition $x(0) \in A$, then the corresponding
> solution $x(t)$ belongs to the set $A$ for all $t > 0$.

**The problem**

Which are the conditions so that any solution starting in the set $A$ converges (asymptotically) to a steady state in the space $A$?

In other words, which are the conditions so that

$$\forall x_0 \in A ~\exists y \in A : \lim_{t \to +\infty} x(t) = y.$$

**Maybe** the question can be restated also as follows: which are the conditions so that the system does not exhibit cyclic solution like centers of limit cycle, or other behavior like chaos?

Are there any theoretical results that can help me?

Comment: The existence of a Lyapunov function would help. With "a steady state" do you mean "some steady state" or do you imply that there is only one?

Comment: @LutzL thanks for the comment. Maybe my question was not so clear, so I added something. I mean, any solution converges to any steady state. I'm not interested for just one steady state.

Comment: @LutzL If I'm able to find a Lyapunov function, then I can conclude that the system for sure will converge to a specific steady state. Suppose that I'm not able to find a Lyapunov function for all the steady states (this is the case for the system $$\dot{x} = x(1-x)(x-0.5),$$ with $N = 1$. How can I prove that any solution will converge to a point in $[0,1]$? For this case, it is very easy to show that. But what can I do in higher dimension ($N>1$)?

Comment: In your example, $V(x)=x^2(1-x)^2$ gives $\dot V=2x(1-x)(1-2x)(x-0.5)=-x(1-x)(1-2x)^2$ which is negative almost everywhere in $[0,1]$, except the unstable stationary point, so bad example. But in general you are right, it will hardly be possible to patch individual local Lyapunov functions into one global one.

Comment: @LutzL exactly.

Comment: One obvious example is gradient systems. You will not find any *general* answer to your question, since it is possible to embed *any* system $\dot x=f(x)$ into, e.g., simplex, that is, you are basically asking for a condition of an arbitrary continuous dynamical system to converge to an equilibrium.

Comment: @Artem do you mean that, if I'm able to prove that my system is a gradient system, then I'm sure that for an arbitrary initial condition the  dynamical system converges to an equilibrium?

Comment: Yes, the exact statement is as follows: if $y\in\omega(x_0)$, where $\omega(x_0)$ is an omega limit set, and $\dot x=f(x)$ is a gradient system then $y$ must be an equilibrium. In general it also requires to show that $\omega$-limit set is non-empty. In your example, however, since you assume that the flow stays in a compact set, then $\omega$-limit set is non-empty and hence any orbit of your system will converge to an equilibrium.

Comment: And after some thought: you will need additionally that your omega-limit set to be discrete. It is possible (although quite complicated) to construct a gradient system with bounded solutions which have the whole unit circle as an $omega$-limit set (each point of which is, of course, an equilibrium).

Comment: @Artem are there some readings that you can suggest which report all these ideas?

Comment: Pick, e.g., Hirsch & Smale classic Differential equations, dynamical systems and linear algebra, it even has some abstract discussion of arbitrary inner products and gradient systems (not easily found in other textbooks). For more involved examples that I mentioned (the set of equilibria that composes omega-limit set) you will probably have to look for some research papers, I do not remember the exact references out of the top of my head.